# Using UCanAccess to read mdb file from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ucanaccess

I am using the MATLAB Database toolbox to read data from MS Access *.mdb files. In the past I did this using the jdbc:odbc bridge 'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.' However, this driver is no longer supported or available, and I am implementing a solution using the UCanAccess driver. This is based on the solution described in the MATLAB Answers forum [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/367357-database-connection-in-2017b). However, I am encountering a driver error and am hoping someone can help offer some suggestions!

[Here is the MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html) on the database() function.

I've downloaded and installed UCanAccess 5.0.0.

Below is my MATLAB code:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\UCanAccess\UCanAccess-5.0.0-bin\ucanaccess-5.0.0.jar');
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\UCanAccess\UCanAccess-5.0.0-bin\lib\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar');
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\UCanAccess\UCanAccess-5.0.0-bin\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar');
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\UCanAccess\UCanAccess-5.0.0-bin\lib\hsqldb-2.5.0.jar');
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\UCanAccess\UCanAccess-5.0.0-bin\lib\jackcess-3.0.1.jar');
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\UCanAccess\UCanAccess-5.0.0-bin\loader\ucanload.jar');

db_path = 'C:/Data/file.mdb';
url = ['jdbc:ucanaccess://' db_path];
conn = database('','','','net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver',url);
```

The connection object is created in MATLAB, but a Warning pops up:

```
WARNING:You shouldn't use 'user' reserved word as column name in the table BatchHistory_Table (it refers to the database user).
 Escape it in your SQL! 
(e.g. SELECT [USER] FROM TABLE WHERE [USER]='Joe')
```

Does this imply something is incorrect or corrupt with my mdb file itself? The mdb files are created by a 3rd party software package, and I can't alter any of the data, column names, or table names. I just want to read the data from the mdb file.

Then when I look at the connection Message, conn.Message, this is:

```
'JDBC Driver Error: UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT unexpected token: AND required: VALUE'
```

I don't know what steps to take next or how to find more information on this Driver Error. Does this have to do with an expected query? I haven't tried querying yet - I first want to open the connection and then make my queries on the mdb file.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Don't add loader\ucanload.jar to your Java classpath if you are adding the other five (5) JARs. ucanload.jar is a separate way of loading the driver and would not be applicable in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have removed ucanload.jar from the Java classpath, but I am still getting the same error. I tested with another file (MATLAB's "tutorial.accdb" file), and was able to connect to this file with no errors, and subsequently execute SQL queries to read data. But with my real working file, I get the exact same '...SNAPSHOT unexpected token: AND required: VALUE' error. Is it possible something in the file itself is causing this error? And if so, how can I ignore or skip this instead of it preventing me from reading the entire file? Thank you!

Comment: Gord, do you have any other ideas on this? I've been unable to resolve this error. I can read my mdb file from MATLAB using the MS Access ODBC driver, but I want to avoid this solution because 1) it requires using a command to first create the ODBC DSN for every single file, and then remove the DSN after reading, and this adds processing time I'd like to avoid, and 2) for some reason this is unstable in MATLAB and causes a program crash about 40% of the time. I have an open case with MATLAB tech support to try to resolve this, but I would prefer to stick with ucanaccess if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Can you open the database file using UCanAccess' `console.bat` or `console.sh` utility? If you get an error on loading, try opening the database in Access itself and run a Compact and Repair Database operation on it.